# Output stream from Process is not being returned over WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have two applications:

1. WPF that is a client
2. Console Application that is WCF service hosted stand-alone

I want to be able to start process through WCF and return an output stream from that process (so I will use process.StandardOutput.BaseStream).

The problem is that once process starts, the returning object which is output stream is not being returned until process exits.

TransferMode in my both programatically created bindings is set to Streamed.

Uploading files **TO** WCF works fine, but problem exists only with returning stream.

**WCF Service Code:**

```
[OperationContract]
    Stream RunTests(string testPackageDll);
```

Implementation:

```
public Stream RunTests(string testPackageDll)
    {
        var p = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Tests\NUnit-2.6.4\nunit-console.exe",
                Arguments = $@"C:\Tests\{testPackageDll} /xml=test-results.xml",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        try
        {
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            return p.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**WPF Application Code:**

```
public void RunTests(string testToRun)
    {            

        string streamLine;

        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(_serviceHandler.Service.RunTests(testToRun)))
        {
            streamLine = reader.ReadLine();
            while (streamLine != null)
            {
                WriteToConsole(streamLine);
                streamLine = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

the _serviceHandler.Service.RunTests(testToRun) method does not return Stream as it suppose to do, instead it is waiting for process to end then returns stream.

What I want to achieve is to read *"live"* stream straight from process.

**UPDATE**

I just found out that Stream is actually being streamed through WCF but only when the output text buffer reaches 12-16 kb, so what I am looking for now is how to change frequency (probably buffer size if there's a chance) of the data. 
I know it would be possible by "chunking" the stream into small parts, but maybe there's some better solution than that?

Comment: Note, that the way you are reading the process output is broken in many ways (it's not easy): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3483

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a better view of known issues! I will bear in mind that once I will get back to that issue